# Code compiles fine in VS2008(3.5) but fails in VS2010 (4.0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, migration

I have a piece of code while goes like below

```
foreach (ConstantsDS.ComponentsRow row in ds.Components) 
      {
        foreach (DevicesDS.ConstantsRow rowC in ds.Constants) 
             {
            if (rowC.ComponentID == row.ComponentID)
                 rowC.SetParentRow(row);
             }
       }
```

This compiles fine in VS2008. I converted the same solution in VS2010 updated the framework in  project properties, then when I try to compile it gives a compile time error.

> "Cannot convert type ConstantsDS.ConstantsRow to
>   DevicesDS.ConstantsRow"

What could be the possible cause.Do I need to make any changes specifically for VS2010 ?